# How to make Bootstrap table,nav pagination work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, pagination

I have the following code  I search all over the internet can't find an example of how to make the pagination work.I want to achive 10 row in a page when there are more pagination to increment and to work when I click next or previos or some page from the pagination menu.I am not front end developer or javascript develeoper so I need help.Thank you for the help.

```
<div class="card card-body border-0 shadow table-wrapper table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="border-gray-200">Iteam</th>
                <th class="border-gray-200">Date</th>                       
                <th class="border-gray-200">Date Time</th>
                <th class="border-gray-200">Data</th>
                <th class="border-gray-200">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Item -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="fw-bold">
                        Data
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="fw-normal">Data</span>
                </td>
                <td><span class="fw-normal">Data</span></td>  
                <td><span class="fw-normal">Date</span></td>                        
                <td><span class="fw-bold text-warning">Due</span></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Item -->
                                     
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="card-footer px-3 border-0 d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <ul id="list_id" class="pagination mb-0">
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link"  href="#">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="fw-normal small mt-4 mt-lg-0">Showing <b>5</b> out of <b>25</b> entries</div>
    </div>
</div>
```